# Wordpress loading fine first time, but fails loading the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which loads perfectly the first time, however, if I reload it in any browser, it gives me all sorts of errors such as these ones in FireFox:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
or
TypeError: document.body is null
```

and this in Chrome, IE and Opera:

```
VM236:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (autoptimize_2389e63….js:8), <anonymous>:1:633)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (autoptimize_2389e63….js:8), <anonymous>:1:12848)
    at autoptimize_2389e63….js:8
```

I have the autoptimize and above the fold plugins installed. The site loads fine despite of the errors, but a soliloqui slider fails.
If I disable the Optimize Javascript Loading from the Above the fold plugin, the errors disappear, but that beats the purpose.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your Optimize Javascript Loading uses $.browser...
The `$.browser` method has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

> [**`jQuery.browser() removed`**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)
>
> The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. **If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin.** We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.
>
> — [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

As stated in the Upgrade Guide you can try using the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to restore this functionality and let jQuery Tools work.

You can check out this solution. It's pretty straightforward, just copy and paste the following lines of code in header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.browser = {};
    (function () {
        jQuery.browser.msie = false;
        jQuery.browser.version = 0;
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
           jQuery.browser.msie = true;
           jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
        }
    })();
</script>
```

just try above function...